# what is better approach to write exports function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, security, veracode

issue is with veracode security scan it is creating flaw in the code so after the compilation it is converting to JS and becuase of "use strict" check it doesn't like exports as global variable i believe , is there way to write this function better to avoid the security scan issues ?

main.ts

```
    import * as Store from "../common/store";
    export function authenticate(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const app = Store.getInstance('sp');
    app.Profile.authenticate(req.body, function(result) {
        res.send(result);
    });
}
```

main.js After compilation

```
function authenticate(req, res) {
    const app = Store.getInstance('sp');
    app.Profile.authenticate(req.body, function (result) {
        res.send(result);
    });
}
exports.authenticate = authenticate;
```

Comment: `export function authenticate(…) { … }` is exactly what you should be writing, and there are no security issues with that. What is veracode complaining about precisely?

Comment: @Bergi as you can see in ts file thats how we are writing however after the compilation JS creating exports module for that particular function

Comment: And that's fine, too, if it is the module format you desire. So, again, what exactly is veracode complaining about?